# Spring redirectAttributes not working in other profiles besides "dev"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I have a controller that is supposed to redirect to another endpoint after processing but it only works when I set the active profile to `dev`. When the profile is not `dev`, the controller returns to the login page instead of redirecting to the profile endpoint.

This is my controller

```
public String completeSignUp(
          @RequestParam final String token, @RequestParam final String userId,
          Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    LOG.debug("About to complete the sign-up process with token: {} and userId {}", token, userId);
    try {
      InputValidationUtility.validateInputs(getClass(), token, userId, model);
      UserDto userDto = updateUserAndSendConfirmationEmail(token, userId, model, httpServletRequest);
      if (Objects.isNull(userDto) || model.containsAttribute(SignUpControllerConstant.SIGN_UP_ERROR)) {
        model.addAttribute(UserConstant.USER_MODEL_KEY, new UserRequestModel());
        return SignUpControllerConstant.SIGN_UP_VIEW_NAME;
      }
      // automatically authenticate the userDto since there will be a redirection to profile page
      UserUtility.authenticateUser(userService, userDto.getUsername());
      model.addAttribute(SignUpControllerConstant.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS_KEY, true);
      model.addAttribute(USER_REQUEST_MODEL_KEY_NAME, new UserRequestModel());
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(ProfileControllerConstant.NEW_PROFILE, true);
      LOG.debug("Redirecting to profile page...");
      return "redirect:/profile";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(SignUpControllerConstant.ERROR_CREATING_USER, e);
      model.addAttribute(SignUpControllerConstant.ERROR, SignUpControllerConstant.ERROR_CREATING_USER);
      return SignUpControllerConstant.SIGN_UP_VIEW_NAME;
    }
  }
```

The profile page requires authentication and has the endpoint `/profile`.

This code works in "dev" profile

Answer (score 0):

I had a bean declared to set cookies to strict which was interfering with the redirection sometimes.

```
@Bean
  WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
    return tomcatServletWebServerFactory -> tomcatServletWebServerFactory.addContextCustomizers(context -> {
      Rfc6265CookieProcessor processor = new Rfc6265CookieProcessor();
      processor.setSameSiteCookies("strict");
      context.setCookieProcessor(processor);
    });
  }
```

Redirection worked once I removed it.